# A property wrapper causes JSONDecoder to fail when property is not in the json string

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder, property-wrapper

I have a data model class with custom rules to deserialize from json. Specifically, the property `flexibleProp` can be defined in JSON as either `String?` or `Int?`. On my model class it should always be `Int?`. I have implemented a `propertyWrapper` to support custom deserialization rules:

```
class PersonInfo: Codable {
    var regularProp: String?
    @FlexibleInt varflexibleProp: Int?
    
    init() {
    }
}

@propertyWrapper struct FlexibleInt: Codable {
    var wrappedValue: Int?
    
    init() {
        self.wrappedValue= nil
    }
    
    init(fromdecoder: Decoder) throws{
        letcontainer = trydecoder.singleValueContainer()
        ifletvalue = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            wrappedValue= Int(value)
        } elseifletintValue = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            wrappedValue= intValue
        } else{
            wrappedValue= nil
        }
    }
    
    func encode(toencoder: Encoder) throws {
        varcontainer = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        trycontainer.encode(wrappedValue)
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let payload1 = "{ \"flexibleProp\": \"123888\", \"regularProp\": \"qqq\" }"
letperson1= trydecoder.decode(PersonInfo.self, from: payload1.data(using: .utf8)!)
let payload2 = "{ \"flexibleProp\": \"\" }"
letperson2= trydecoder.decode(PersonInfo.self, from: payload2.data(using: .utf8)!)
let payload3 = "{ \"flexibleProp\": \"sss\" }"
letperson3= trydecoder.decode(PersonInfo.self, from: payload3.data(using: .utf8)!)
let payload4 = "{ }"
letperson4= trydecoder.decode(PersonInfo.self, from: payload4.data(using: .utf8)!)  // FAILS HERE <------------
```

And it works in most cases correctly, only the last test case fails, when the `flexibleProp` property is completely missing in the json string (key and value are not defined):

```
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ keyNotFound : 2 elements
    - .0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "flexibleProp", intValue: nil)
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"flexibleProp\", intValue: nil) (\"flexibleProp\")."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

I'm having no issues with the other `String?` property `regularProp`, when missing in json, it stays nil in the result, but for the `flexibleProperty` it fails to deserialize the whole object instead of just keeping the property nil. What is the best way to tell `JSONDecoder` to properly handle that property when it's not defined in the json string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: this answer is adapted from a similar post of mine [on the Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/cleaner-way-to-decode-missing-json-keys/40523/7), explaining the behavior.)

Unfortunately, a property wrapper cannot influence `Codable` synthesis to allow a value for a specific key to be omitted entirely.

When you write

```
@FlexibleInt varflexibleProp: Int?
```

the compiler generates the equivalent of

```
private var _varflexibleProp: FlexibleInt
var varflexibleProp: Int? {
    get { return _varflexibleProp.wrappedValue }
    set { _varflexibleProp.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

Because `_varflexibleProp` is the "real" property (and `varflexibleProp` is just a computed property), for the purposes of encoding and decoding, the compiler will encode and decode `_varflexibleProp`. This is crucial, because it's what allows `FlexibleInt` to intercept encoding and decoding of the property with its own `Codable` conformance at all.

But it's important to note that the type of `_varflexibleProp` is `FlexibleInt`, which is not `Optional` — it just contains an `Optional` inside of *it*. This is important, because `Optional` values are special for `Codable` synthesis:

- When the compiler encounters an `Optional` property, it generates a call to [`encodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyedencodingcontainer/encodeifpresent(_:forkey:)-45la3)/[`decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/decodeifpresent(_:forkey:)-2hn6i), which skips encoding the value altogether if it is `nil`, and crucially, *skips decoding the value altogether if the key is not present in the keyed container*
- When the compiler encounters a non-`Optional` property, it instead generates a call to [`encode(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyedencodingcontainer/encode(_:forkey:)-3a74m)/[`decode(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/decode(_:forkey:)-1u4zx), which unconditionally encode the value even if `nil`, and *unconditionally requires the key to be present on decode*

It's that last point that's problematic: because `_varflexibleProp` is not `Optional`, the compiler attempts to initialize it as

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    _varflexibleProp = try container.decode(FlexibleInt.self, forKey: .varflexibleProp)
    // ...
}
```

`decode(_:forKey:)` has to check whether a key is present before anything can even be decoded, and so in your case, an error is thrown before `FlexibleInt.init(from:)` is ever called — because there isn't even any data for you to possibly decode from.

If the compiler did try to use `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)`, it would have to provide some sort of default value for `_varflexibleProp`, which isn't always obvious how to do:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    // `varflexibleProp` is a computed property, which can't be assigned to in an initializer.
    // You have to write to `_varflexibleProp`, which is the real property.
    _varflexibleProp = try container.decodeIfPresent(FlexibleInt.self, forKey: .varflexibleProp)
    // ❌ error: Value of optional type 'FlexibleInt?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'FlexibleInt'

    // ^ oops! what value do we assign to _varflexibleProp?
}
```

Here, it might *seem* obvious that `_varflexibleProp` should be assigned a value of `FlexibleInt()`, but the compiler has no way of knowing whether that has the semantics you want it to have (e.g., what if it has side effects?). In the linked Swift Forums thread, the property wrapper author didn't give it a zero-argument initializer, but instead had a single-argument initializer that took a `wrappedValue`; this can very quickly devolve into a guessing game of how to initialize this non-`Optional` property, which may not be safe for the compiler to do at all.

---

Ultimately, this behavior isn't related to `JSONDecoder` specifically, but to how the compiler synthesizes `Codable` conformance. The workaround for now would be to implement `PersonInfo.init(from:)` directly, using `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` yourself and initializing `_varflexibleProp` with a default value.

There's a bit more discussion in the thread about how this could possibly be handled in the future, so it's worth a read if you're curious. (And, now that macros are coming to Swift 5.9, it's possible that in the future, `Codable` conformance could be pulled out of the compiler the way that it's written now, and instead implemented as a macro — and if so, toggles could be added to better influence how that happens.)

Comment: Is it possible to decode all the rest of the properties as it was before and specify `decodeIfPresent` only for this given `flexible` property? Or do I need to decode each property by specifying its name and type?

Comment: @Mando No, unfortunately: if you specify your own `init(from:)` or `encode(to:)` method, the compiler machinery for synthesizing conformance doesn't kick in at all, so you have to implement the method in its entirety, including all of the properties you want.